# Right click to select which script to run

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file

I have a bunch of .bat files that each do a certain task.

Instead of clicking on the one I want directly, is it possible to create a single bat file that allows me to click on it to present a list of scripts to select the one I want to run somewhat like a menu when you right click on a file? And preferably in the task bar?

How would I write something like this?

Comment: it is certainly possible to create a menu selection system with one or more bat files. Not sure about taskbars and clicking. I always run bats from within a shell just to avoid any cases where the script closes so quickly that you can't confirm from the output that the job worked correctly.

Comment: Hi there!  Unfortunately, we're not a script-writing service, and as-is this question is very broad, and shows no research effort (what have you tried already, what were the results?).  To get started, perhaps being by investigating the [`choice`](http://www.computerhope.com/choicehl.htm) command, and come back with specific questions if/when you get stuck on specific problems while implementing your batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create (cascaded or not) simply customizable menu: **Add a Toolbar to the Taskbar**

You can use the **Toolbars feature** to create a new toolbar on the taskbar to quickly access a folder and its files located anywhere on your PC. To create a new toolbar, right-click on the empty area of the taskbar and click “**New toolbar**”.

Browse to the location where the folder containing your scripts is saved and then click “**Select Folder**” button to add the toolbar.

If your scripts do not reside in a single folder (and its subfolders) then you could gather *shortcuts* of your scripts to such a folder.